# Decoding JSON data from bytes changing float value to int

Tags: json, go

The following code to un-marshall json data from from byte array changing the type of float value to int.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    byt := []byte(`{"num":6.0}`)
    var dat map[string]interface{}
    fmt.Println(byt)

    if err := json.Unmarshal(byt, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dat)
}
```

Here is the playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/60YNkhIUABU

Is there anyway to keep the type as it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unmarshalled number already is a `float64`. You can check this by adding a line to the end of your playground example to print out the type of the data:

```golang
fmt.Printf("%T\n", dat["num"])
```

If you want to have this be more explicit, you could try changing the type of `dat` from `map[string]interface{}` to `map[string]float64`.

Comment: Is there any way that float64 keeps 6.0 as 6.0 as is. Becuase I am pushing this unmarshall data to elasticsearch and elasticsearch treating it as a int. So later on if I get something like decimal number elasticsearch is throwing an error.

Comment: Can you put an example of the code where you are using this data in your question? Probably you need to use some kind of format code, like `fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", dat["num"])`.